# Unity movie texture audio does not sync

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to play a movie on UNITY 5.1.2 RawImage. 
It works, but the audio is way out of sync with the movie and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code that plays the movie:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

//Does not support mobile
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class Movie : MonoBehaviour
{
        public bool playOnStart = true;
        #if !(UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE) || UNITY_EDITOR
        public MovieTexture movieTexture;
        #endif

        public AudioSource audioSource;

        IEnumerator Start ()
        {
                if (audioSource == null) {
                        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
                }

                audioSource.Stop ();
                if (playOnStart) {
                        Play ();
                }
            yield return 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Play the movie
        /// </summary>
        public void Play ()
        {
            #if !(UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE) || UNITY_EDITOR
                if(movieTexture == null){
                    Debug.Log("Movie texture is undefined");
                    return;
                }
                GetComponent<RawImage>().enabled = true;
                GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = movieTexture;
                movieTexture.Play ();
                audioSource.clip = movieTexture.audioClip;
                audioSource.Play ();

            #endif
        }
}
```

It is attached to a RawImage object with a RawImage script attached to it. I want to play the movie when a player presses a button on a certain location.

Thanks